# Evitando arrays como valores ao usar array_merge_recursive()

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
$vagas = array(
  '2017-09-22' => array(
    '11:30' => 2,
    '12:00' => 3,
    '15:00' => 1
  ),
  '2017-09-23' => array(
    '9:00' => 5,
    '10:00' => 3,
    '11:30' => 2
  )
);
```

Esse array é atualizado através de um formulário, onde o usuário pode informar múltiplas datas, horários e o número de vagas para os horários escolhidos.

```
$vacancy_days = array_filter($_POST['vacancy-days']);
$vacancy_number = wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['vacancy-number']);
$vacancy_number = intval($vacancy_number);
$vacancy_hours = array_filter($_POST['vacancy-hours']);

$created_vacancies = array();
foreach ($vacancy_days as $day) {
  foreach ($vacancy_hours as $hour) {
    $created_vacancies[$day][$hour] = $vacancy_number;
  }
}
```

No final, mesclo com o array já existente:

```
$vacancies = get_option('vagas');
$new_vacancies = array_merge_recursive($vacancies, $created_vacancies);
update_option('vagas', $new_vacancies);
```

O `array_merge_recursive()` funciona bem, inclusive incluindo novos horários em datas já existentes. O problema acontece quando informo um horário já existente em uma data já existente. Neste caso, ele cria um array para armazenar os dois números de vagas (antigo e o novo).

Como faço para resolver isso? Manter somente o número de vagas novo.

Comment: No caso, se o usuário informasse a data 2017-09-23, 9:00h, 1 vaga, o valor 5 deveria ser substituído por 1?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Isso mesmo. No momento, ele criar um array com os dois valores.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido:

```
$vacancies = get_option('vagas');
$new_vacancies = array_merge_recursive($vacancies, $created_vacancies);

foreach($new_vacancies as $key => $vaga){
foreach($vaga as $key2 => $horario){
  if(is_array($horario)){
    $last_value = end($horario);
    $new_vacancies[$key][$key2] = $last_value;
  }
}
}

update_option('vagas', $new_vacancies);
```